# R Functions require package declaration when they are included from another file?

Tags: r, aggregate, package

I am writing some data manipulation scripts in R, and I finally decided to create an external .r file and call my functions from there. But it started giving me some problems when I try calling some functions. Simple example:

This one works with no problem:

```
change_column_names <- function(file,new_columns,seperation){
    new_data <- read.table(file, header=TRUE, sep=seperation)
    colnames(new_data) <- new_columns
    write.table(new_data, file=file, sep=seperation, quote=FALSE, row.names = FALSE)
}
change_column_names("myfile.txt",c("Column1", "Column2", "Cost"),"|")
```

When I crate a file "data_manipulation.r", and put the above `change_column_names` function in there, and do this

```
sys.source("data_manipulation.r")
change_column_names("myfile.txt",c("Column1", "Column2", "Cost"),"|")
```

it does not work. It gives me  `could not find function "read.table"`  error. I fixed it by changing the function calls to  `util:::read.table`  and  `util:::write.table` .

But this kinda getting frustrating. Now I have the same issue with the  `aggregate`  function, and I do not even know what package it belongs to.

My questions: Which package  `aggregate`  belongs to? How can I easily know what packages functions come from? Any cleaner way to handle this issue?

Answer (score 4):

The `sys.source()` by default evaluates inside the base environment (which is empty) rather than the global environment (where you usually evaluate code). You probably should just be using `source()` instead.

You can also see where functions come from by looking at their environment.

```
environment(aggregate)
# <environment: namespace:stats>
```

Comment: Thanks. Making it source fixes the issue.

Answer (score 1):

For the first part of your question: If you want to find what package a function belongs to, and that function is working properly you can do one of two (probably more) things:

1.) Access the help files

`?aggregate` and you will see the package it belongs to in the top of the help file.

Another way, is to simply type `aggregate` without any arguments into the R console:

```
> aggregate
function (x, ...) 
UseMethod("aggregate")
<bytecode: 0x7fa7a2328b40>
<environment: namespace:stats>
```

The namespace is the package it belongs to.

2.) Both of those functions that you are having trouble with are base R functions and should always be loaded. I was not able to recreate the issue. Try using `source` instead of `sys.source` and let me know if it alleviates your error.

Comment: Yes. Making it source fixes the issue. Thanks for the additional info by the way.